# Windows Search Indexing SSD

Tags: windows, laptop, ssd, windows-search

I just bought a new SSD (Vertex4 from OCZ, 256G) and installed Windows 8 with it on my laptop. I am not using an external hard drive to keep extra data (paging, temp files etc) because I am using a laptop and do not want to carry it around with me.

My question is, if I disable Windows indexer (Windows Search service), does Windows still search files under the search (Windows 7 Start menu search/Metro UI Windows 8 search)? Since the indexer was meant to search for files by indexing them, does this mean that Windows will not search new files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want the index? Too big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the Windows Search service turns off the Search Indexing, but of course the Search option will still be present and work, albeit slowly since it has to trawl through your files every time you search. Turning off Windows Search from the *Turn Windows Features on or off* dialog however will completely remove and disable Search.